# Problem converting React, Material-UI functional component to class component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React and this is my first ever post to SO. I found a great Combo-Box-like React / Material-UI component that I'd like to use. However my application uses class components and this one is a functional component... The class components choke when trying to include this one because it uses hooks for styling and managing state, which are only allowed in functional components. So, I converted it to a class component. The problem is, the class component won't focus the cursor to allow me to type into the `TextField`.

I have scoured through the Javascript code in the debugger in side-by-side mode trying to find what is different about the functional (works) vs. class (doesn't work) component, in addition to comparing the CSS. I see no differences, so obviously I'm looking in the wrong place.

In the debugger, I can see in the react-select js code for `onControlMouseDown` where `_this.focusInput();` is called, and at that time the cursor *is* focused in the input field. However once I hit Go and the re-render completes, the cursor is no longer there and my typing is completely ignored, unlike with the functional version of same component where the cursor remains after the re-render.

Have also tried setting properties on the input component such as `autoFocus=true`, `disabled=false`, among others.

1) Functional CodeSandbox (works): https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-4fgow

2) Class CodeSandbox (doesn't work): https://codesandbox.io/embed/ecstatic-frog-87b8r

Snippet of react-select code that I compared the 2 components in with the debugger is below. Note that `openMenuOnClick` is true in both the working and non-working instance and `this.state.isFocused` is `false` in both - the only thing different is the end behavior unfortunately.

```
_defineProperty(_assertThisInitialized(_assertThisInitialized(_this)), "onControlMouseDown", function (event) {
    var openMenuOnClick = _this.props.openMenuOnClick;

    if (!_this.state.isFocused) {
        if (openMenuOnClick) {
            _this.openAfterFocus = true;
        }
        _this.focusInput();
    } else if (!_this.props.menuIsOpen) {
        if (openMenuOnClick) {
            _this.openMenu('first');
        }
```

I expect to be able to type into this component and have it present me with selections that contain what I typed, but I cannot type into it at all - the cursor doesn't focus.

Comment: Actually I don't see any problems, why you could not use a functional component within a class component. Are you sure this does not work?

Comment: You are correct! I revisited, and found that when I included the functional component in my class component using new IntegrationReactSelect() is when I got the "you can't use Hooks from inside a class component" error. When I included it using <IntegrationReactSelect/>, it worked. I can't believe I overlooked this through everything I tried, I'm pretty flabbergasted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So I modified the functional component to be used by a class component and now I am having trouble passing the suggestion list as a prop: https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-4fgow

Comment: Finally got the passing of the suggestion list via prop to work (https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-zxot5) - should be all set now. Thanks again for the help.

Comment:  Now you solved all your problems by yourself!